# how to see if 2 binary trees are similar?

Tags: c, binary-tree

I need to check two binary trees to see if they are similar... meaning if they have the exact same structure and then the data on the same levels (but the data doesn't need to be in the same structure)...

Example

```
     A               A
  |     |         |     |
  B     C         C     B
 | |   | |       | |   | |
 D E   F G       G D   E F
```

The left binary tree is similar to the right (obviously there are MANY variations!)

Here's the psuedocode I have thus far:

```
if( tree1 == NULL && tree2 == NULL ) return TRUE;

if( tree1 == NULL || tree2 == NULL ) return FALSE;

if( tree1->label != tree2->label ) return FALSE;

return (   TRUE
        && (  (   similarTrees(tree1->left, tree2->left)
               && similarTrees(tree1->right, tree2->right))
            || (   similarTrees(tree1->left, tree2->right)
                && similarTrees(tree1->right, tree2->left))  ));
```

My reasoning was that since the two left sub trees could be equal and the two right sub tree could be equal OR the left and right of one and the right and left of the other could be equal, then this logical recursion should work... it does not, however.

similarTree is the recursive function

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: A small note: You don't need the `TRUE && (...)` expression. Just return the actual expression without `TRUE &&` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code and the example does not match.

Code assumes that trees are equal if each subtree contains the same root label and the same children, albeit in an arbitrary order.

The example, on the other hand, does not hold true for this. For example in the left tree, the children of `C` are `F` and `G`, whereas in the right `G` and `D`.

To write code to check if these are similar, you must first clearly define what it means to be similar. E.g. should a label exists in both trees. Should it exists at the same level? Can it occur more than once?

Comment: The code is most likely NOT right... The definition I have for similarity is that the structure is identical. Meaning, if one tree has a left child null and right child, then the other must also have a left child null and right child (just an arbitrary example). The second definition is that there must be a label of the same value somewhere in the tree's level. So for instance, in that example... A can not be swapped with anything... B & C can only be swapped with each other... D, E, F, G can all be swapped with each other in any variation.

And btw, thank you for your help!

Comment: In that case I would recommend that you would traverse the tree, accumulate the nodes on each level. The result will be a collection of collections of nodes. Once you have done that for both threes, you could compare the collections. Of course, the collections must be considered equal regardless of the inner order. For example, the left example tree could be collected into: `[[A], [B, C], [D, E, F, G]]` and the right `[[A], [C, B], [G, D, E, F]]`, which are similar (as the order of the labels is ignored within each collection).

Comment: I figured out a better way. Since we are using binary trees, instead of making a new data structure, I would dump both trees into 2 dummy trees. Then I will sort the two dummy trees recursively and sort them based on level. Then I would compare the two dummy trees for identicality. The order is to first check for proper structure then do the sorting of the dummy trees. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can solve whether they're same structure for first step, and use my step for second step

for a tree level, you can collect data from the same level into the the same set (or sorted list)

Obviosly that if a tree's all level set is equal to another tree's ,and they have the same structure, these two trees are similar

Comment: Having the same set does not imply having the same structue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [breadth first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

**1.** You  can get the elements on the same level.

**2.** then compare the levels whether they have same elements by sorting the lists obtained.